# Should we call ads in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, admob, iad

We have a tab-heavy app, which has 5 tabs to use back and forth. We have iAds and admobs(as backup for countries without iAd), and we 'call' the ads in viewDidLoad. Would it make a difference to call them in viewDidAppear instead? And then remove them in viewDidDisappear or shomething not to screw up the frames etc? Would this give more impressions etc?

Comment: I was thinking that the ad stayed through the enitre load period, and that a new ad only would be requested when viewDidLoad was called next time, which technically could be never. Apparently an ad cycles in time, and only stays up for a minute or so. I'm not sure though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**viewDidLoad:**

> viewDidLoad
>   Called after the controller’s view is loaded into memory.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

> Discussion
>   This method is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory. This method is called regardless of whether the view hierarchy was loaded from a nib file or created programmatically in the loadView method. You usually override this method to perform additional initialization on views that were loaded from nib files.

---

**viewDidAppear:**

> viewDidAppear:
>   Notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view hierarchy.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

> Parameters
>   animated
>   If YES, the view was added to the window using an animation.
>   Discussion
>   You can override this method to perform additional tasks associated with presenting the view. If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation.

**Answering**

So viewDidLoad is called slightly earlier than viewDidAppear: , the only difference is that when viewDidAppear: the view have been already drawn, instead in viewDidLoad the view has still to be drawn.

So answering to your questions:

> Would it make a difference to call them in viewDidAppear instead?

If calling the ads is  a slow operation, then you would see first the view appearing in it's color, and the ads after a few interval of time.However this has to be too slow to make a real difference.

> And then remove them in viewDidDisappear or shomething not to screw up the frames etc?

It doesn't "screw up frames", that for sure.

Comment: So, calling ads in ViewDidAppear would force the ad-system to give me another ad, thus giving more impressions and more income? Which basically is my original question. Like, instead of leaving me stuck with the one loaded from viewDidLoad until the process is shut down or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

you just need call it in viewDidLoad

Comment: Yeah, but CAN I call it in viewDidAppear? That would force the ad-system to give me ANOTHER ad, right? Thus giving more impressions. ?

Answer (score 0):

Putting your ad code in viewDidAppear: (and removing it in viewDidDisappear:) will certainly give you more impressions, but unless you're a whitelisted pub, you're probably getting paid on a cost per click basis anyway ([AdMob Help Center article](http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1619753)).

In this case, instead of having the overhead of creating and destroying GADBannerView objects on tab changes, you might as well create a singleton GADBannerView that you use throughout your TabbedController (look at an example [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/source/browse/?repo=adcatalog-ios#git/AdCatalog/Classes/AdvancedLayoutUseCases/TabbedViewExample)).